# Create a new column based on values of other columns in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, greenplum

What i have

```
customer_id
   1
   2 
   2
   1
   3
```

What i want (for all customer id's with 1 ,i want to flag as valid ,rest of the customer id's as invalid in the new column  "warining_customer_id"

```
customer_id    warining_customer_id
   1             Valid
   2             Invalid
   2             Invalid
   1             Valid
   3             Invalid
```

Comment: Hint:  `CASE` expression.

Comment: Use `update table1 set warining_customer_id = ...`

Answer (score 1):

Here an example

```
SELECT   customer.customer_id AS customer_id,
         CASE WHEN customer.customer_id = 1 THEN 'Valid' ELSE 'Invalid' END
             AS warning_customer_id
  FROM   (SELECT   1 AS customer_id FROM DUAL
          UNION ALL
          SELECT   2 AS customer_id FROM DUAL) customer
```